# parsec using between to parse parens

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

If I wanted to parse a string with multiple parenthesized groups into a list of strings holding each group, for example

```
"((a b c) a b c)"
```

into

```
["((a b c) a b c)","( a b c)"]
```

How would I do that using parsec? The use of `between` looks nice but it does not seem possible to separate with a beginning and end value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While jozefg's solution is almost identical to what I came up with (and I completely agree to all his suggestions), there are some small differences that made me think that I should post a second answer:

1. Due to the expected result of the initial example, it is not necessary to treat space-separated parts as individual subtrees.
2. Further it might be interesting to see the part that actually computes the expected results (i.e., a list of strings).

So here is my version. As already suggested by jozefg, split the task into several sub-tasks. Those are:

1. Parse a string into an algebraic data type representing some kind of tree.
2. Collect the (desired) subtrees of this tree.
3. Turn trees into strings.

Concerning 1, we first need a tree data type

```
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.String
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))

data Tree = Leaf String | Node [Tree]
```

and then a function that can parse strings into values of this type.

```
parseTree :: Parser Tree
parseTree = node <|> leaf
  where
    node = Node <$> between (char '(') (char ')') (many parseTree)
    leaf = Leaf <$> many1 (noneOf "()")
```

In my version I do consider the hole string between parenthesis as a `Leaf` node (i.e., I do not split at white-spaces).

Now we need to collect the subtrees of a tree we are interested in:

```
nodes :: Tree -> [Tree]
nodes (Leaf _) = []
nodes t@(Node ts) = t : concatMap nodes ts
```

Finally, a `Show`-instance for `Tree`s allows us to turn them into strings.

```
instance Show Tree where
  showsPrec d (Leaf x) = showString x
  showsPrec d (Node xs) = showString "(" . showList xs . showString ")"
    where
      showList [] = id
      showList (x:xs) = shows x . showList xs
```

Then the original task can be solved, e.g., by:

```
parseGroups :: Parser [String]
parseGroups = map show . nodes <$> parseTree

> parseTest parseGroups "((a b c) a b c)"
["((a b c) a b c)","(a b c)"]
```

Comment: Awsome Answer Thank you so much aswell. i prefer this method

Comment: @chris I've tried this and I see one problem with it.. the nodes function replicates the content of all nested parentheses. It works as it should for me when I replace the last line of nodes function to this: `nodes t@(Node _) = t`

Comment: P.S. Ah, I see that was the point of OP. Nevermind then :-) I needed something different - just to parse contents of parentheses, which include parentheses. Something like `func() { hello{...} }`, but with the contents flattened. With this simple change it does what I needed, so a big thanks!

Answer (score 11):

I'd use a recursive parser:

```
data Expr = List [Expr] | Term String

expr :: Parsec String () Expr
expr = recurse <|> terminal
```

where `terminal` is your primitives, in this case these seem to be strings of characters so

```
 where terminal = Term <$> many1 letter
```

and `recurse` is

```
       recurse  = List <$>
                  (between `on` char) '(' ')' (expr `sepBy1` char ' ')
```

Now we have a nice tree of `Expr`s which we can gather with

```
collect r@(List ts) = r : concatMap collect ts
collect _           = []
```

Comment: Maybe it's just me ;), but I find `(r :) $ ts >>= collect really hard to read. Wouldn't `t : concatMap collect ts` be more readable? But questions of taste aside, I think the base-case should not just return `[]`.

Comment: Oh sorry, my mistake. `[]` in the base-case is needed (since we only want parenthesized groups in the result).

Comment: @chris Hmm yeah... I've been working on a code thats list monad heavy, I'll edit

Comment: Thank you for this! I could never have come up with something that elegant!